# How do I show a Google Maps-esque slow AJAX request warning?

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

I'm currently using ajaxStart, ajaxStop and ajaxSetups to successfully show a "LOADING" div when pages are being loaded using jQuery's .load() function.

What I'd like to do is add a "This is taking a while" warning DURING the ajax request, like Google Maps....

So, five seconds after ajaxStart fires, the "LOADING" div becomes "This is slow". That should then disappear on ajaxStop....

What I have currently (below) does not work. On loading the page, the "LOADING" div appears and disappears correctly, but then the "This is slow" error appears 5000 milliseconds later, despite the page having successfully loaded.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
error:function(x,e){
    if('parsererror'==e) {
        $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#technical-error').fadeIn('fast');
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#technical-error").fadeOut('fast');
        }, 3000);
    } else if('timeout'==e) {
        $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#timeout-error').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else if ( "status" in x ) {
        if(0 == x.status){
            $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#offline-error').fadeIn('fast');
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#offline-error").fadeOut('fast');
            }, 3000);
        }else if (404 == x.status){
            $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#404-error').fadeIn('fast');
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#404-error").fadeOut('fast');
            }, 3000);
        }else if(500 == x.status){
            $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#500-error').fadeIn('fast');
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#500-error").fadeOut('fast');
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
    else {
        $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#unknown-error').fadeIn('fast');
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#500-error").fadeOut('fast');
        }, 3000);
    }
}
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
$("#loading-warning").fadeIn('fast');
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
    $("#timeout-error").fadeIn('fast');
}, 5000);
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
$("#loading-warning").fadeOut('fast');
clearTimeout();
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(){
$('.ajax-warnings').fadeOut('fast');
$('#loading-error').fadeIn('fast');
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $("#loading-error").fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);
});
```

Would be really grateful if someone can point me in the right direction!

UPDATE:

In response to Korvin I now have the following code - the timeout error now doesn't appear at all.

```
var loadingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
        $("#timeout-error").fadeIn('fast');
    }, 5000);

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
$("#loading-warning").fadeIn('fast');
setTimeout(loadingTimer);
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
$("#loading-warning").fadeOut('fast');
clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after lots of help from Korvin, I've come up with this solution to my problem:

```
var loadingTimer = null;

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
$('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
$("#loading-warning").fadeIn('fast');
loadingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.ajax-warning, ajax-errors').fadeOut('fast');
        $("#timeout-error").fadeIn('fast');
        },3000);
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
$(".ajax-warning, .ajax-errors").fadeOut('fast', function(){
    clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
});
});
```

Essentially, what this does is show a LOADING div (a bootstrap alert div, sorry for the confusion) and a "This is slow" div (another bootstrap alert, in red this time) after 3 seconds of loading for every AJAX event on my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setTimeout in there that gets cleared on the ajax response, something like this:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ alert('Woah, this is taking so long!'); },500);
$.post('myscript.format',{data:data},function(e) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     do(stuff);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Korvin - I've added an update to my question, including your suggestion (I think!), but now the timeout error doesn't appear at all.....

Comment: You set it to 5 seconds, I doubt an ajax call takes more than 5 seconds. Also, you've incorrectly implemented it, you're running `setTimeout()` on an active timeout, which won't work.

Comment: Yes, the 5 seconds is deliberate, although I suppose 3 seconds might be more appropriate. As for the implementation, I'm afraid you're going to have to help me out again: I'm not sure where the $.post function fits into my scripts.....

Comment: [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a post Ajax call, it's an example of an ajax call with the function being the callback.

Comment: Right, sorry - I'm with you now. I'll try that out and see how it goes!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm here to help :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16739/discussion-between-erve1879-and-korvin-szanto)